# How to create WPF vector images

Tags: wpf, icons, expression-blend

I have an application that has icons which at the moment are PNG's. I'm trying to create vector images, however I cant seem to find any good tutorials.
There are a few that are pointing to this http://templarian.com/2011/08/06/tutorial_creating_an_icon/ 
but this is just exporting the file as a png.

I have seen an icon online that is in the same kind of xaml format i want

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="RestoreIcon">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingGroup.Children>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M 898.726,800.022L 913.274,800.022L 913.274,804.022L 918.607,804.022L 918.607,815.978L 904.06,815.978L 904.06,811.978L 898.726,811.978L 898.726,800.022 Z M 913.274,811.978L 906.57,811.978L 906.57,813.278L 915.964,813.278L 915.964,807.909L 913.274,807.909L 913.274,811.978 Z M 901.237,803.908L 901.237,809.278L 904.06,809.278L 904.06,804.022L 910.631,804.022L 910.631,803.909L 901.237,803.908 Z M 910.631,809.278L 910.631,807.909L 906.57,807.908L 906.57,809.278L 910.631,809.278 Z ">
          <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <Pen Thickness="1" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#C7141414"/>
          </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingGroup.Children>
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

This is drawing an icon from the GeometryDrawing information. I'm looking how i can go about making my own GeometryDrawing data?

Ideally i would like to be able to import my png image, draw over the tope of it and get GeometryDrawing data.

Comment: Personally, for quick and simple stuff, I'll just make it in Blend with the pen tool etc. For more complex vector images I'll make them in the Adobe Illustrator and export them to XAML and clean out all the unnecessary clutter xaml that comes in the exported result before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "import my png image, draw over the tope of it and get GeometryDrawing data", then the standard way is to use Blend.  Or, you could use InkScape.  How to do this is another subject itself, but Blend is probably where you want to start.